# If statement in PHP not working, Doesn't run if OR else

Tags: php

Title.... The if statement below isn't working, i added to console log to check what the condition is returning and it checks out. Anyone know whats wrong with it? the variable $check is created in another file not here. If the variable check wasn't putting out the correct value it would obviously not work but it does put out the right value.

session.php

```php
<?php
// mysqli_connect() function opens a new connection to the MySQL server.
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sports world");
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session
$user_check = $_SESSION['login_user2'];
$p = $_SESSION['login_user3'];

$check = $_SESSION['check'];
?>
<script> let check = "<?php echo $check; ?>";
console.log(check)</script>
<?php

if ($check === 'user') {
    // SQL Query To Fetch Information Of User
    $query = "SELECT Username from staff where Username = '$user_check'";
    $ses_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);

    $login_session = $row['Username'];


    // SQL Query To Fetch Information Of User
    $query2 = "SELECT StaffCode from staff where Username = '$user_check' AND Password = '$p'";
    $ses_sql2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql2);

    $cust = $row2['StaffCode'];
    $_SESSION['CustCode'] = $cust;


    // SQL Query To Fetch Information Of User
    $query3 = "SELECT StaffGivenName As 'Given Name', StaffSurname As 'Surname' from staff where StaffCode = '$cust'";
    $ses_sql3 = mysqli_query($conn, $query3);
    $row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql3);

    $name1 = $row3['Given Name'];
    $name2 = $row3['Surname'];
    $_SESSION['Given Name'] = $name1;
    $_SESSION['Surname'] = $name2;


    // SQL Query To Fetch Information Of User
    $queryAccountDeatils = "SELECT StaffDob As 'Date of Birth', StaffGender As 'Gender', StaffAddress1 As 'Address', StaffAddress2 As 'Region', StaffPostCode As 'Post Code', StaffPhone As 'Phone Number', StaffEmail As 'Email', StaffTFN As 'Message Preferences', StaffEmerConName As 'Member Type', StaffEmerConPhone As 'Sports' from staff where StaffCode = '$cust'";
    $ses_sql4 = mysqli_query($conn, $queryAccountDeatils);
    $row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql4);

    $Dob = $row4['Date of Birth'];
    $Address = $row4['Address'];
    $Gender = $row4['Gender'];
    $Region = $row4['Region'];
    $PostCode = $row4['Post Code'];
    $PhoneNumber = $row4['Phone Number'];
    $Email = $row4['Email'];
    $MessagePref = $row4['Message Preferences'];
    $MemberType = $row4['Member Type'];
    $Sports = $row4['Sports'];
    $_SESSION['Date of Birth'] = $Dob;
    $_SESSION['Address'] = $Address;
    $_SESSION['Gender'] = $Gender;
    $_SESSION['Region'] = $Region;
    $_SESSION['Post Code'] = $PostCode;
    $_SESSION['Phone Number'] = $PhoneNumber;
    $_SESSION['Email'] = $Email;
    $_SESSION['Message Preferences'] = $MessagePref;
    $_SESSION['Member Type'] = $MemberType;
    $_SESSION['Sports'] = $Sports;
} else if ($check === 'staff') {
    // SQL Query To Fetch Information Of User
    $query = "SELECT Username from login where Username = '$user_check'";
    $ses_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);

    $login_session = $row['Username'];


    // SQL Query To Fetch Information Of User
    $query2 = "SELECT CustCode from login where Username = '$user_check' AND Password = '$p'";
    $ses_sql2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql2);

    $cust = $row2['CustCode'];
    $_SESSION['CustCode'] = $cust;


    // SQL Query To Fetch Information Of User
    $query3 = "SELECT CustGivenName As 'Given Name', CustSurname As 'Surname' from customers where CustCode = '$cust'";
    $ses_sql3 = mysqli_query($conn, $query3);
    $row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql3);

    $name1 = $row3['Given Name'];
    $name2 = $row3['Surname'];
    $_SESSION['Given Name'] = $name1;
    $_SESSION['Surname'] = $name2;


    // SQL Query To Fetch Information Of User
    $queryAccountDeatils = "SELECT CustDob As 'Date of Birth', CustGender As 'Gender', CustAddress1 As 'Address', CustAddress2 As 'Region', CustPostCode As 'Post Code', CustPhone As 'Phone Number', CustEmail As 'Email', CustMsgPref As 'Message Preferences', CustMemberType As 'Member Type', CustSports As 'Sports' from customers where CustCode = '$cust'";
    $ses_sql4 = mysqli_query($conn, $queryAccountDeatils);
    $row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql4);

    $Dob = $row4['Date of Birth'];
    $Address = $row4['Address'];
    $Gender = $row4['Gender'];
    $Region = $row4['Region'];
    $PostCode = $row4['Post Code'];
    $PhoneNumber = $row4['Phone Number'];
    $Email = $row4['Email'];
    $MessagePref = $row4['Message Preferences'];
    $MemberType = $row4['Member Type'];
    $Sports = $row4['Sports'];
    $_SESSION['Date of Birth'] = $Dob;
    $_SESSION['Address'] = $Address;
    $_SESSION['Gender'] = $Gender;
    $_SESSION['Region'] = $Region;
    $_SESSION['Post Code'] = $PostCode;
    $_SESSION['Phone Number'] = $PhoneNumber;
    $_SESSION['Email'] = $Email;
    $_SESSION['Message Preferences'] = $MessagePref;
    $_SESSION['Member Type'] = $MemberType;
    $_SESSION['Sports'] = $Sports;
}
```

[image: console log]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried using == instead of === ?

Comment: Just did, didn't work

Comment: So what does `var_dump($check);` output then?

Comment: Add delimiters to your console log (why not output the value in PHP?) to make sure there's no whitespace around. And maybe add an `else` branch for when `$check` isn't "user" or "staff"

Comment: I've added a screenshot to show the console log, i added var_dump($check); but i have no idea where that outputs. "And maybe add an else branch for when $check isn't "user" or "staff" " no need, program dies if it isn't one of those 2 at an  earlier stage.

Comment: Don't worry about the offset values, they disappear when the if works properly.

Comment: Your if obviously works fine, the first notice is on line 21 which is in the if statement, your request doesn't work

Comment: If i remove the if, it all works fine and there are no errors.....

Answer (score 0):

Well.... this is embarrassing, the condition staff and user were on the wrong statements just had to switch them.